# Calculating $P(X-E(X)\geq \mathrm{SD})$ for a normal random variable $X$

Tags: probability, standard-deviation

If you'd have to calculate the following probability of an $X\sim \mathrm{Normal}$: $$P(X-E(X)\geq \mathrm{SD}),$$

how would you calculate it? And if the calculation will be for $4\cdot\mathrm{SD}$, how does it matter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then
$$
\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1).
$$

Comment: ok thanks, got that. so i'm getting the 1-Ф(1) for the SD. what are the news in the same calcultaion for 4*SD?it there anything differnt?

Comment: The exact same calculations applies: $$P(X-\mu\geq 4\sigma)=P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\geq 4\right)=1-\Phi(4)$$

Comment: @adamco One difference is that many _tables_ of the values of $\Phi(x)$ give values only for $x \in (0, 3.0)$ or $x \in (0, 3.5)$ and so you may need to get more extensive tables or look for a calculator (there are many available, even on-line) that will tell you the value of $\Phi(4)$.

Comment: Note, for large values in $\Phi$ (i.e. > 3) asymptotic approximations start to be pretty accurate for most uses.